# How can I detect if Chromium has crashed?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chromium

I have a machine running a webpage through chromium in a display case.
When the webpage crashes and displays "He's Dead Jim" I need an automated CLI solution to re-start the browser.

I'm currently working on a solution which takes a screenshot every 1 minute and if that screenshot looks like the "He's Dead Jim" page, knows that the page has crashed.
There must be a better way.

How can I detect if Chromium is displaying a crashed page?